# Print watermarks on every printer in every printjob

Tags: printing, watermark, printers

I hope to find a solution to a problem I've been struggling with for the past three months.

The task is as follows: To protect information, I need to develop a software solution that can "force" any printer to print a document from ANY program with WATERMARKS WITHOUT USER'S ACTION to put watermarks on this document .

To simplify, let me describe it: A user can be working anywhere and suddenly wants to print a document. They open Word, LibreOffice, or even a text editor. They click "print," and the document comes out already with watermarks applied, without any user intervention. In other words, the watermarks need to be applied programmatically and without the user's involvement. This is crucial.

There used to be a software solution for this request, but it has been lost.

How can I develop a software solution to automatically overlay watermarks on documents printed from any program, without user intervention?

We have already tried solutions for overlaying images on documents using EXTREMELY expensive add-ons in C#. and its not "by default", this solution required user's actions. Additionally, we've experimented with 'capturing' the document when sending it to print, slowing it down, retrieving its name, converting it to PDF with watermarks. It's an excruciatingly long process that heavily burdens both RAM and the processor.

Currently, we have an idea in progress regarding a universal driver from Microsoft's examples. The idea is to add a default watermark printing function to the universal driver. It's last hope, so to speak.

Comment: Maybe come back when you've finished your "idea in progress".

Comment: LEADTOOLS ePrint can create a virtual [Task Printer](https://www.eprintdriver.com/help/v6.0/Professional-Edition/#ePrintTaskPrintersConfigurationDialog.htm) that is configurable to automatically add [Stationary/Overlay](https://www.eprintdriver.com/help/v6.0/Professional-Edition/#Stationery_Overlays_Toolbar.htm) watermarks to the output and redirect the job to an [existing printer](https://www.eprintdriver.com/help/v6.0/Professional-Edition/#BatchPrintDialog.htm). A free evaluation is available from [here](https://www.eprintdriver.com/Download) (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)